# Azure Service Fabric Explorer returns always 403

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I just deployed an secured Service Fabric Cluster (EncryptAndSign) with a LoadBalancer to an Azure Subscription. Deployment took some time but it worked as expected. Also I can connect to the cluster via PowerShell:

```
$connectionEndpoint = ("{0}.{1}.cloudapp.azure.com:19000" -f 
   "mycluster", "somewhere")

Connect-serviceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $connectionEndpoint `
  -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 `
  -X509Credential `
  -ServerCertThumbprint "..." `
  -FindType FindByThumbprint `
  -FindValue $clusterCertificate.Thumbprint  `
  -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

It is also possible for me to deploy an application to the Cluster via Port 19000 using VisualStudio. Within in the Azure Portal everything looks good, no warning, no errors.

Unforunately I am not able to connect via Port 19080 to the Explorer. As I try to connect via the LoadBalancer I receive a Connection-Timeout. So established a RDP-Connection to one of the Nodes in the Cluster and tried to access the Explorer locally via

```
localhost:19080/Explorer
```

But here I receive a Http-Error 403 (Forbidden) which might be the reason for the Connection timeout via Load-Balancer (as the probe is always receiving 403). Accroding to the [Azure Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-visualizing-your-cluster/#connect-to-a-remote-service-fabric-cluster):

> "If you attempt to connect to Service Fabric Explorer on a secure
>   cluster, your browser will ask you to present a certificate in order
>   to gain access."

Well, I was not prompted to present any certificate. Did I miss something? Is there anything special to configure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, this one was not that tricky - but you have to know it and I did not read it anywhere yet. As long as you do not configure any Andmin Client Certificate all your request to the Explorer (:19080/Explorer) end up with an 403 as described above.

You can add an Thumbprint of an Admin Client Certificate in the Portal:
[image: Azure Portal - Add Admin Certificate]

And it should (untested) also work with the following setting in your ARM Template:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters",
  ...
  "properties": {
    ...
    "ClientCertificateThumbprints": [
      {
        "CertificateThumbprint": "THUMBPRINT_HERE",
        "IsAdmin": true
      }
    ],
  ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, it should be possible (also untested) to specify multiple certificates in this array.

Be sure that you generate and use a SHA1 fingerprint hash. A SHA256 fingerprint can be input through the Azure Portal, but will result in HTTP 403 responses without warnings as to what the problem is.

Comment: Hi @fivet. I am having the same problem as you had. I understand I need to add an Admin Client cert, but which cert do I add? Do I need to make a new one? How do I link it to my browser? Sorry for all the newbie questions. I've never used client side certs before so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Btw, like you I can access the cluster through Visual Studio's Cloud Explorer

Comment: @NickBarrett, as s you can have multiple ClientCerts defined you can mange permissions with them, which allows you e.g. to share the non-admin-cert with others so they can read-only access the cluster (but they are not allowed to do any admin-actions like deactivting a node). You can also remove the cert-thumbprints via e.g. Azure Portal to revoke access to the person with that cert. For this reason I would recommend you to create at least one new Certificate. The browser integration depends on your browser. In Firefox navigate to Settings -> Advanced -> Certificates to manage the certs.

Comment: Hmm weird, it keeps redirecting me to [login.microsoftonline.com](http://login.microsoftonline.com) and yet `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "<SNIP>.cloudapp.azure.com:19000" -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint $serverCert.Thumbprint -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue $clientCert.Thumbprint -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My` works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you get redirected to login.microsoftonline.com because you configured AAD for authentication? I am not sure if you still can login in to the Service Fabric Explorer with a web browser using the certificate after you configured AAD. Maybe there might be different URL for certificate-login? It's just an idea, but maybe it helps..

Comment: You are right. I flagged a support issue with Microsoft and they found the same thing.  Will fix. :)